# How to Determine Metal Device VR Support

Tags: swift, macos, virtual-reality, metal

I am looking to create a macOS 10.13 application that tests for virtual reality support. What would be the best way to test a Mac for VR support, considering the CPU, GPU, and connectivity requirements?

Also, given a `MTLDevice`, is there  a way to check for VR support using the Metal API?

I have tried to check the default system Metal device for `macOS GPUFamily1_v3` support, but that does not completely answer the question of whether a device supports VR on macOS. The code below is what I use to test support for the Metal feature set.

```
let defaultDevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
    print(defaultDevice?.supportsFeatureSet(.macOS_GPUFamily1_v3))
```

Comment: You've *described* what you've tried, but haven't shown the code for that. It could help. It's trivial to find out the OS version running on a device - as I'm sure you already know - but why (and how) *specifically* are you saying that `macOS GPUFamily1_v3` *"does not completely answer the question"*?

Comment: Thank you @dfd. I will update the question with the code I'm using. I say that checking for `macOS GPUFamily1_v3` support doesn't answer the question because for a few reasons. First of all, this doesn't tell you anything about the CPU spec and if it is good enough for VR. Also, this doesn't tell you if the GPU could power a head mounted display at the target frame rate. Lastly, this doesn't indicate the Thunderbolt spec of the device.

Comment: Cool questions, what about MTLCopyAllDevices? At least you can get list of all devices, open question is how to switch to external GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "Metal VR Support". There is no special capability or GPU-level feature required to render for VR. Furthermore, there is no such thing as a "spec good enough for VR" as it relies completely on the resolution and frame rate of the particular headset used, as well as your application.

You can query the [IOService](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/ioservice) layer to get GPU model and specs, but you will have to extrapolate the capabilities for yourself based on your personal requirements.